# QT4: Is it possible to make a QListView scroll smoothly?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4

I have a QListView in Icon mode with lots of icons, so that a scrollbar appears, but the scrolling is not smooth and this IMHO confuses the user since it jumps abruptly from one point to another at each scroll. I would like to make the scrolling smooth but I didn't find anything in the docs. Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you would like to redefine the scrolling behavior of the widget. I guess what happens is that listview is getting scrolled by the item's height whenever users hits a scroll arrow (marked as b on the image below).

[image]

For a vertical scroll bar connected to a list view, scroll arrows typically move the current position one "line" up or down, and adjust the position of the slider by a small amount. I believe line in this case it is an icon's height. You can adjust items height by installing and [item delegate](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html#sizeHint) (setItemDelegate) and overriding its sizeHint method. Though this would not help you to solve this problem. What you could try is to create a QListView descendant and override its updateGeometries method. There you can setup the vertical scrollbar step to the value you want, I guess 1 or 2 for this task. Below is an example of the custom listview:

```
class TestListView : public QListView
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TestListView(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    virtual void updateGeometries();
};

TestListView::TestListView(QWidget *parent) :
    QListView(parent)
{
    //???
}

void TestListView::updateGeometries()
{
    QListView::updateGeometries();
    verticalScrollBar()->setSingleStep(2);
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Interesting. I will try this soon. Thanks!

Comment: Setting singleStep and pageStep in updateGeometries seems to work properly for mouse scroll.

Answer (score 28):

Maybe [QListView.setVerticalScrollMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#verticalScrollMode-prop)([QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#ScrollMode-enum))

Comment: It seems like the correct property but it didn't work. It scrolls just like before.

Comment: I think this is the simplest way to achieve smooth scrolling and it worked for me

Comment: This seems like the correct property but I couldn't get it to work as well. Does anyone have any solutions? It seems to playing around with effect `verticalScrollBar()->singlestep()`

Comment: `_my_listview->setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel);` worked perfectly fine. Scrolling by dragging the bar itself is now smooth. Using Scrollwheel it still jumps a few items.

Answer (score 1):

I have a QlistWidget* in ui->barra_scroll and I feel very smooth with this.

```
QScrollBar *qsb = ui->barra_scroll->verticalScrollBar();
qsb->setSingleStep(5);
```